# System.Exception when trying to run converted VS 2010-project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've installed the latest version of Visual Studio 2012, with the latest hotfix.

I have a perfect working project, made in VS 2010, that I converted (automatically) to a VS 2012 project.
It builds, but when I try to run it, there is a pop-up: System.Exception. Anyone who knows this problem?

Comment: You should really try stepping into the code using a debugger.

Comment: Can't do that. It doesn't even run, it just shows that popup.

Answer (score 0):

You should install VS 2010 SP1 before you convert any VS 2010 project to VS 2012.
If you haven't done this, the opened project will cause many unrelated behavior.

Also any installer/setup project in VS 2010 will not be opened in VS 2012.

Comment: Yes, I have Visual Studio 2010 SP1, so that can't be the problem. I think the problem is I installed VS 2012 RC, then SP1 and then the July hotfix. Investigating it now.

Comment: Installing RC1? You should uninstall VS 2012 RC 1 first before installing SP1 or VS 2012 RTM (release) version.